# Still getting 304 with expires header

Tags: javascript, http, apache2

I'm using this `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2692000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2692000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2692000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2692000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2692000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2692000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2692000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2692000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
  </FilesMatch>
  Header unset ETag
  Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
```

Most of my files get loaded from browser cache, but some get a 304.

Some of them are just symlinks in the webserver directories, but not all of them.
Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: "Most of my files get loaded from browser cache, but some get a 304." The 304 (Not Modified) response results in the browser loading the resource form its cache.

Comment: True story, but when I add an expire header, the browser shouldn't request the server anymore, till the file he cached expires.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. The browser will _always_ send requests to all resources but if the server responds 304, the browser knows that it doesn't actually have to retrieve the body of the response. (And also, a proper server implementation will _not_ send the body in such a case.)

Comment: But how come, that most of the files get a "200 (from cache)" with about 1-4ms response time and some of them a "304 169B" with 20 - 250ms response time?